# kill: SIGSTOP: invalid signal specification error in bash script

Tags: bash, command-line, kill

When I use `kill` on command line it works.

```
kill -SIGSTOP 1234
```

But if I use in bash script file I get this error:

```
kill: SIGSTOP: invalid signal specification
```

sh file is

```
#!/bin/sh
kill -SIGSTOP 1234
```

How can I use `kill` in bash script? I tried this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/bash -c "kill -SIGSTOP 1234"
```

but it does not work.

Comment: You can use e.g  `trap 'kill -s SIGSTOP 1234' EXIT`  in a bash script. Also it is `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @val0x00ff, I tried `trap 'kill -s SIGSTOP 1234' EXIT` but I get same error

Comment: Does the answer I posted illustrate the scenario? Do you still get the error? It should work interactively and as well as within a script.

Comment: @val0x00ff, my problem solved when I changed `#!/bin/sh` to `#!/bin/bash`. I always use `#!/bin/sh` and now I really do not know why it does not work.

Comment: I see. Well probably because you need to enable posix mode?  Are you on a Mac?  `set +o posix; kill -SIGSTOP 1234`  could solve the problem as well!

Comment: No. I am on Linux

Comment: There's a discrepancy between your question title and body (SIGINT vs SIGSTOP and bash vs sh).

Comment: @Stéphane Chazelas  sorry. I edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To start with:  `SIGSTOP` will temporarily stop the process but keep in memory so it can be continued later on using `SIGCONT` system call. You can use the following little snippet to see what happens

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

sleep 100 &
pid=$!
kill -s SIGSTOP "$pid"
sleep 2
kill -s SIGCONT "$pid"
```

You'll see what the script does interactively.

So to get your script working using `#/bin/sh` shebang you'd do something like

```
#!/bin/sh

set -x
set +o posix
sleep 100 &
pid=$!
kill -s SIGSTOP "$pid"
sleep 2
kill -s SIGCONT "$pid"
set -o posix
```

Comment: I think it will be better answer if you add something about `#!/bin/bash`

Comment: @user4757345 if that solved your problem, just modify the answer and add the explanation.

Comment:  POSIX doesn't specify a "posix" option (that's a `bash` option), and of course does not specify what would happen when you turn it off. Your answer doesn't make any sense. If you want to use a `bash` specific feature, start the script with `#! /bin/bash`, don't make it a sh script that assumes sh is bash and then disable the sh mode.

Comment: Well according to posix specs, there is no `SIG` in `sh`.  So again instead of commenting on every answer I post you better edit the answer and provide the right one. How's that?

Answer (score 20):

The [standard (POSIX) syntax](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/kill.html) is:

```
kill -s STOP "$pid"
```

That is, without the `SIG` prefix. Some shell implementations, support `kill -s SIGSTOP` or `kill -SIGSTOP` as an extension but that's not standard nor portable.

The UNIX specification (POSIX+XSI) also allows:

```
kill -STOP "$pid"
```

And

```
kill -19 "$pid"
```

Though which signal number is `SIGSTOP` is not specified and may change between systems and even architectures for a same system, so should be avoided.

Comment: As I explained in my edited answer. `set +o posix` will allow the usage of `SIGTERM`, `SIGSTOP` etc.  I do agree that `set -o posix`  at the end is not necessary. It's more a habit.  I'm not sure what the significance or the added value is in your answer.

Comment: `set +o posix` will only allow SIGTERM/SIGSTOP in bash when bash is started in posix mode, not with any other implementation of sh. So you rely on your /bin/sh being bash. Don't do that, use `#! /bin/bash` if you want to use bash specific features.

Comment: @val0x00ff Stricktly speaking, `pdksh` and `yash` also have a `posix` option. `pdksh` supports `kill -SIGSTOP` regardless of whether that option is enabled or not. `yash`, like `bash` also forbids `kill -SIGSTOP` when the `posix` option is off, and gives a more specific error message in that case: _kill: SIGSTOP: the signal name must be specified without 'SIG'_. `dash` and AT&T `ksh` `kill` builtins don't support `kill -s SIGSTOP`. `zsh`'s and procps-ng's do.

Comment: Well ok, I didn't notice the `-SIGSTOP` I thought passing `-s` to `kill` was mandatory. Thanks for the explaination! Learnt something new today.

Answer (score 3):

I am facing the same problem. All answers here did not address the true cause of the issue. Inside the script the `kill` used is the built-in **provided by the shell**, that is why you are having the error. While in your terminal, the `kill` used is the separate executable located at `/bin/kill`. To fix the issue, inside your script you must explicitly use the `/bin/kill` and not the built-in shell version. Therefore you write it like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
/bin/kill -s SIGHUP 14344
```